# In what conditions application looses connection with flash media server?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, air, chat, flash-media-server

I am creating a small chat application using Flash Media server. I have already created all my user interface components in Flex(Adobe AIR).

problem what i am facing is this when i am sending a Object through FMS sometime it send successfully but most of time it become a problem and application loss netconnection.

so i would like to know, **rather than closing application what are other condition when FMS loses network connection?**

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the trial version of FMS? If the network connection is not lost due to obvious reasons (internet disconnection) then connections may be getting rejected by FMS if it exceeds the permissible number of max connections. The trial I believe has a limit of 10 or 15 max connections. In a multi user videochat scenario this can be reached with just 4 users since each user will use 4 connections (one streaming their cam and 3 watching the other 3 user cams). If this is the case FMS will show an error showing maximum connections reached in the logs.